# Can't get past cannot get read property style of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've looked through everything and I can't solve this issue... my html code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cool Game</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="para">Some text here</p>
        <img src="MinerLeft.png"id="img">
    </body>
</html>
```

My javascript code is:

`document.getElementById("img").style.left = "100px";`

In the console it prints:

```
JavaScript.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at JavaScript.js:1
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("img").style.left = "100px";
});
```

To make sure the Elements are loaded before running scripts against them.

Here are the docs for why this works: [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Also css style left doesnt do anything if the position isn't set so maybe try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("img").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("img").style.left = "100px";
});
```